# EACCES (Permission denied) even after giving permission

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, exoplayer2.x

I have an Android app targeting SDK 28 so I have the permissions to deal with. I check that the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is set, but when Exoplayer tries to read the file (which I verified did exist) I see

> com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20190610_200249.mp4: open failed:
>   EACCES (Permission denied).

I can play an asset (file baked into the app) just fine as well as playing from the Internet. I just cannot play a local video stored in my ...DCIM/Camera directory for some reason. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please? My code looks like this:

```
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, DefaultTrackSelector())
    playerView.player = player
    player?.addListener(this)

    //TODO: Change this when we are given the embedded video
    val dataSource = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "Exoplayer"))
    var path: String = ""
    var mediaSource: ExtractorMediaSource

    if (passedUrl == PLAY_TUTORIAL) {
        path = "asset:///tutorial_video.mp4"
        mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSource).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(path))
    } else {
        path = passedUrl

        val file = File(path)
        val uriPath = Uri.fromFile(file)

        Timber.d("Path is $uriPath and that file exists = ${file.exists()}")


        mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSource).createMediaSource(uriPath)
    }

    //Setting this to 0 will keep the controls from being hidden otherwise it's in milliseconds
    playerView.controllerShowTimeoutMs = 1500

    player?.prepare(mediaSource)
```

When I run the code I see this in the logs:

```
2019-06-13 21:54:35.048 5774-5774/com.android.myapp D/ViewTutorialActivity: Path is file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20190610_200249.mp4 and that file exists = true

2019-06-13 21:54:35.076 5774-5846/com.android.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Setting buffer count to 3, min_undequeued 1, extraBuffers 0

2019-06-13 21:54:38.077 5774-5968/com.android.myapp E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20190610_200249.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:73)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe it's SELinux problem . Has your device rooted?  try __adb shell setenforce 0__. and __adb shell getenforce__ return permissive means it takes effect ,and try ur code again.

Comment: I see in the logs about FileNotFoundException so requesting you to check the file again. If file is there try moving it to /sdcard/Downloads directory.

Comment: How do you check for the permission?

Comment: The device is not rooted. It's a Pixel 3XL running Android Q beta.

Comment: I tried another file. This time in /storage/emulated/0/Download/. The same thing happens.

Comment: I check permissions the standard way using checkSelfPermission. The code looks like this: private fun setupPermissions() {
        val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )

        if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Timber.i("Permission to read external storage is already granted")
        }
        else {
            Timber.i("Permission to read external storage denied")
            makeRequest()
        }

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is an Android Q thing. There is a work around by enabling legacy support. The same code works perfectly on prior Android versions.